# MySQL & PHP: Divide two numbers from two different tables with the same date

Tags: php, mysql, loops, foreach

I have this two tables:

Table 1: **TBL_USD_AUD**

```
+----+------------+----------+
| id | date       | value    |
+----+------------+----------+
| 1  | 2015-04-24 | 1.278400 |
+----+------------+----------+
| 2  | 2015-04-23 | 1.287200 |
+----+------------+----------+
| 3  | 2015-04-22 | 1.288300 |
+----+------------+----------+
| 4  | 2015-04-21 | 1.291500 |
+----+------------+----------+
| 5  | 2015-04-20 | 1.294300 |
+----+------------+----------+
```

Table 2: **TBL_USD_EUR**

```
+----+------------+----------+
| id | date       | value    |
+----+------------+----------+
| 1  | 2015-04-24 | 0.923873 |
+----+------------+----------+
| 2  | 2015-04-23 | 0.928333 |
+----+------------+----------+
| 3  | 2015-04-22 | 0.930839 |
+----+------------+----------+
| 4  | 2015-04-21 | 0.934579 |
+----+------------+----------+
| 5  | 2015-04-20 | 0.932575 |
+----+------------+----------+
```

How can I select both table as such:

```
$x = "SELECT date,rate FROM `currency`.`tbl_usd_aud` WHERE `date` >= (NOW() - INTERVAL 40 DAY)";
```

and:

```
$f = "SELECT date,rate FROM `currency`.`tbl_usd_eur` WHERE `date` >= (NOW() - INTERVAL 40 DAY)";
```

and then somehow I would like to get foreach value on same date make the following equation:

```
if ($x['date'] == $f['date']){
   echo "EUR-AUD: ".(1/$x['rate'])*$f['rate'];
}
```

Comment: You can use `inner join` instead. and looping the records without doing calculation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might as well do the calculation in the DB as well:

```
  SELECT a.date, a.rate x, e.rate f, e.rate/a.rate f_over_x
    FROM tbl_usd_aud a
    JOIN tbl_usd_eur e
      ON e.date = a.date
   WHERE a.date >= CURDATE() - INTERVAL 40 DAY
```

N.B. I prefer `CURDATE()` to `NOW()` as it involves less implicit conversion and also that `(1/x)*y = y/x`

Answer (score 1):

This might helps you

```
SELECT a.date,a.rate,b.rate,(1/a.rate)*b.rate as eur_aud
FROM tbl_usd_aud a
LEFT JOIN tbl_usd_eur b on b.date = a.date
WHERE a.date >= (NOW() - INTERVAL 40 DAY)
```